# Matrices with same height

Tags: matrices

I want to write a matrix equation and my current code is following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1         & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0 \\
      \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    &           & \vdots \\
      0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    & \vdots \\
      \vdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0      \\
      \vdots    &           & 0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu    \\
      0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0         & -1/h      & 1/h    \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
      T^{(j+1)}(0) \\
      T^{(j+1)}(h) \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      T^{(j+1)}(N\cdot h)
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      T(0) \\
      f(h) \\
      f(2h)  \\
      \vdots     \\
      f((N-1)\cdot h)    \\
      blabla
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

however, the resulting matrices have slightly different heights. How do I set them to be the same? Result is in the attached picture:[image]

Comment: Can you wrap your code into a minimal compilable document? It makes it easier for people to play with it, and shows which packages are needed to create the fragment you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest solution, i.e., the one that requires the least amount of additional typing, involves increasing the value of `\arraystretch`. Its default value is `1.0`; increasing it to about `1.8` at the start of the `equation` environment should do the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:xyz}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}  % default value: 1.0
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1         & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0 \\
      \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    &           & \vdots \\
      0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    & \vdots \\
      \vdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0      \\
      \vdots    &           & 0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu    \\
      0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0         & -1/h      & 1/h    \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
      T^{(j+1)}(0) \\
      T^{(j+1)}(h) \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      T^{(j+1)}(N h)
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      T(0) \\
      f(h) \\
      f(2h)  \\
      \vdots     \\
      f((N-1) h)    \\
      \text{blabla}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

For consistency reasons, I don't think that increasing the `\arraystretch` is a good idea. However, if we correctly understand the cause of this behavior, we may come with a simple and exact solution. The main cause of this problem here is writing symbols of different heights in the three matrices, namely, the `\vdots` and `\ddots` symbols which are higher than the rest of the symbols.

To remedy this, one should deliberately introduce redundant `\vdots` (or `\ddots`) so that the three matrices can have the same number of them. The second matrix requires only one because it has only three `\vdots` while the first one has four of them. Similarly, the third matrix requires three `\vdots` since it has only one `\vdots`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\D}{\vphantom{\vdots}}  

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1         & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0 \\
      \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    &           & \vdots \\
      0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    & \vdots \\
      \vdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0      \\
      \vdots    &           & 0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu    \\
      0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0         & -1/h      & 1/h    \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
      T^{(j+1)}(0)   \\
      T^{(j+1)}(h)\D \\
      \vdots         \\
      \vdots         \\
      \vdots         \\
      T^{(j+1)}(N\cdot h)
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      T(0) \D         \\
      f(h) \D         \\
      f(2h)\D         \\
      \vdots          \\
      f((N-1)\cdot h) \\
      blabla
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** *(In response to the OP's comment)*

If you don't like typing that `\D` command in every row, try this **automatic** alternative:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\vphantom{\vdots}\arraybackslash}c}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\left (
    \begin{array}{@{}*5{c}V@{}}
      1         & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0 \\
      \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    &           & \vdots \\
      0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    & \vdots \\
      \vdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0      \\
      \vdots    &           & 0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu    \\
      0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0         & -1/h      & 1/h    \\
    \end{array}\right )
    \cdot \left (
    \begin{array}{@{}V@{}}
      T^{(j+1)}(0) \\
      T^{(j+1)}(h) \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      T^{(j+1)}(N h)
    \end{array}\right )
    =\left (
    \begin{array}{@{}V@{}}
      T(0) \\
      f(h) \\
      f(2h)  \\
      \vdots     \\
      f((N-1) h)    \\
      blabla
    \end{array}\right )
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which gives the first equation below.

[image]

Now compare equation 1 (for my code above) and equation 2 (using the `\arraystretch` method). Which one do you think is better? And look how they are inconsistent. Imagine that you have two consecutive paragraphs one is single-spaced and the other is almost double-spaced (except for captions, etc.). Of course they will look bad.

Besides, changing the `\arraystretch` requires trial and error. How would we know in advance that this `1.8` will be just the right value? Why not `1.5`, for example?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on the "consistency reasons" that would speak against resetting `\arraystretch`. For sure, in my answer the scope of the redefinition of `\arraystretch` is local to a particular `equation` environment; I can't tell what potential inconsistencies might follow from such an approach.

Comment: honestly I think that Mico's solution is much more straightforward and works for me really well. I actually don't see why this should be more consistent. this will result in rows 1-4 being taller that 5,6. if I wanted all rows to have the same height I would have to add `\D` to every row, which actually isn't much that different from using `\arraystretch` and seems as a bit more tedious task

Comment: @Tom83B  - Please see my edit for explanation.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you made clear(er) the connection you make between some equation "looking better" and it being "more consistent". Relatedly, what is inconsistent about the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}1.8` method? Presumably, it's not the fact that the resulting rows all have the same height, right?

Answer (score 3):

Here, I just turn all `pmatrix` environments into `\parenMatrixstack`s and `\parenVectorstack`s.  The inter-column gap in the matrix is governed by `\setstacktabbedgap{}` and the inter-row baselineskip is governed by `\setstackgap{L}{}`.  This answer requires my `tabstackengine` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \parenMatrixstack{
      1         & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0 \\
      \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    &           & \vdots \\
      0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu       & \ddots    & \vdots \\
      \vdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0      \\
      \vdots    &           & 0         & \mu       & \lambda   & \nu    \\
      0         & \cdots    & \cdots    & 0         & -1/h      & 1/h    
    }
    \cdot
    \parenVectorstack{
      T^{(j+1)}(0) \\
      T^{(j+1)}(h) \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      \vdots     \\
      T^{(j+1)}(N\cdot h)
    }
    =
    \parenVectorstack{
      T(0) \\
      f(h) \\
      f(2h)  \\
      \vdots     \\
      f((N-1)\cdot h)    \\
      blabla
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]